# If X and Y are normal rv's and linearly correlated, what can we say about (X+Y) and (X-Y)?

Tags: r, distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed but correlated variables, what can we say about the distributions of $A = X+Y$ and $B = X-Y$?

Are $A$ and $B$ correlated? Can we prove or otherwise with a simple $R$ - script?

Comment: There is no such thing as "linear correlation". What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what can we say about the distributions of $A=X+Y$ and $B=X−Y$?

See the [Bivariate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) and [Affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) sections on the Wiki page for the multivariate normal distribution.

Then you will see that

$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix} = F\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}$$

with

$$F=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

which yields a co-variance matrix for $\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}$ which is $F\Sigma F^\top$. Thus, the co-variance is $\sigma_X^2 - \sigma_Y^2$.

> Are $A$ and $B$ correlated?

It depends as shown above.